# How do I get the diagonal of a tensor of rank higher than 2 along selected axis in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have an Tensor of shape `tf.shape(input)=(Batch_Size,Channels,N,N)` my goal is it to calculate and output which contains all diagonal elements along axis 2&3. So that `tf.shape(output)=(Batch_Size,Channels,N)`

There is the function `tf.diag_part(input)` but it doesn't let me select the axis I want to consider. How can I define a function that does this for me?

Could following code work?

```
Batches=[]
for batch in input:
    diagonalpart=tf.diag_part(batch)
    Batches.append(diagonalpart)
output=tf.stack(Batches)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tf.linalg.diag_part](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/diag_part) should does exactly what you want, e.g:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Input shape: (2, 2, 4, 4)
input = np.array([
                [ [[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [9, 8, 7, 6],
                   [9, 8, 7, 6]],
                  [[5, 4, 3, 2],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4]] ], 
                [ [[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [9, 8, 7, 6],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4]],
                  [[5, 4, 3, 2],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [9, 8, 7, 6]] ] 
                                ])

print(tf.linalg.diag_part(input))
```

will outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[1 6 7 6]
  [5 2 7 4]]

 [[1 6 7 4]
  [5 2 7 6]]], shape=(2, 2, 4), dtype=int32)
```